# New way to write CSS variable defaults in Polymer

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0, css-variables

Why has the Polymer team changed the way they define default CSS variable values in Polymer elements? Below is an example:

*Old style*

```
color: var(--my-value,--default-value);
```

*New style*

```
color: var(--my-value,var(--default-value));
```

Are there any new specs for custom CSS variables? Does it have any advantage? Or is it some other reason altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "old style" from Polymer 1.x (i.e., `var(--a, --b)`), while succinct, is technically invalid according to the [CSS variables spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/#using-variables).

The [Polymer 2.0-preview notes](https://github.com/polymer/polymer/tree/2.0-preview#css-custom-property-shim) indicate the motivation to properly conform with the spec is to support native CSS properties:

> The following invalid styling syntax was previously accepted by the 1.0 custom property shim. In order to support native CSS Custom Properties, rules should be correct to use only natively valid syntax:
>
> - ...
> - `var(--a, --b)`
>
>   - Should be `var(--a, var(--b))`

Comment: I went through the `preview notes` still somehow i missed it. Anyways, thanks

Comment: By the way not the polymer team changed that, the spec is changed for the native CSS custom properties and they just following the change.